# Where is a question on Radiobiology and Dosimetry going to best be answered?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions, tags, asking-questions

I want to ask a purely theoretical question (Radiobiology and Dosimetry) on the Bragg Curves (plots of the energy loss of ionizing radiation (KeV/μm usually) on the y-axis during its travel through matter (distance travelled usually in cm)) of some heavy particles (basically I just want to ask for (to be given) the plots themselves since I can't find any of them in my internet searches) specifically Protons, Alpha Particles (Helium Nucleii), Carbon Ions (I think +4 Carbon is used in CIRT) and Osmium Ions (Preferably Osmium +8) and possibly a suggested alternative.

I want to compare the Bragg Curves and posit that Radiation Therapy with Alpha Particles are a better alternative that either Proton Therapy or CIRT (greater LET and RBE than Proton Therapy but less fragmentation than CIRT).

Ideally I would like a heavy particle that had a point mass Bragg Curve (it would have 0 energy loss in all but one point) and furthermore the Radiation Oncologist could manipulate at what depth the energy loss would happen (the energy would be deposited). Sparing everything else the damage (I am ignoring the damage done from free radicals and only considering SSBs and DSBs)

Should I ask Physics, Engineering, Medicine, Biology, some other SE?

Answer (score 4):

I think the question itself is kind of vaguely described and seems to consist of two separate sub-questions. Try to ask focused questions and I would recommend splitting them up. I think I read multiple questions: 1)

> *I want to compare the Bragg Curves and posit that Radiation Therapy with Alpha Particles are a better alternative that either Proton
> Therapy or CIRT (greater LET and RBE than Proton Therapy but less
> fragmentation than CIRT).*

If this is a question, and not just the question premise, it would be more suitable for Physics imo, because it is about particle penetration.

Then I read another quite loosely linked question 2)

> *Ideally I would
> like a heavy particle that had a point mass Bragg Curve (it would have
> 0 energy loss in all but one point) and furthermore the Radiation
> Oncologist could manipulate at what depth the energy loss would happen
> (the energy would be deposited). Sparing everything else the damage (I
> am ignoring the damage done from free radicals and only considering
> SSBs and DSBs)*

This seems more like an idea, or a thought than a question, but if it's about clinical feasibility it is a more clinical question and would be best suited at MedicalSciences I guess.

More importantly, try to formulate (a) specific question(s) with a single question mark in it, not more. Make sure to add prior research to focus it really well. In the end it will become much clearer where this question should go to. In the interim, I think Physics or Medical Sciences, for now.

Comment: The first question is more of a request. I quess I could ask "What (maybe How) are the Bragg Curves of Protons, Helium Nucleii, Carbon Ions and Osmium Ions?" but probably "Please give me the Bragg Curves." would work best. I could also ask if they could please give me the Bragg Curves but then it would not be much of a question even if it had a questionmark.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos asking for the curves would be possible, but that would be akin to what they call *gimme the code* questions over at StackOverflow - not the best of question I must say.

Comment: I could then ask where I could find them. These curves (the plots) are the results of measurements and research. They are not the result of cognition (of the person answering the question) but a large experimentative process.